# How to add a text file into a bash script then work with that text file

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scripting, terminal

I need to read into my script 3 parameters, the first 2 are numbers and the third one is a `.txt` file.

For example:

```
example.sh 3 2 exam.txt
```

And with the third parameter `exam.txt` that already has some text in it I need to search for lines with `head` and `tail`.

The question is how do I read that `exam.txt`? Tried `"$3"` but when working with it, it only uses the word, not the file.

Comment: Do you want to read its contents, or just pass the path to the file to other programs? Also, please include the exact steps you already tried and also what you have researched so far.

Comment: if you want to dump the content of the life cat $3 will do that for you, however, depending on what you want to do with the content there are better ways to handle this.

Comment: Please tell us what you exactly do *"when working with it"*

Comment: For example I need to make a script that will output lines of text from line$1 to line $6 so the first parameter is the starting line and the second parameter is the end line of the output. And the third parameter is going to be a text of my choosing. And from that random text it needs to output those lines. The text of course being some file with the ending .txt

Comment: Every command you can use to process a file will accept one or more filenames on the command line, either as an argument or via redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$3 is just going to be the string of the filename that you're passing the bash script. You will need to do something with that filename string to get anything useful out of it.

If you just need to get the content of the file itself you could `cat $3` and that will cat the contents of the filename you've passed as that argument.

If you need to iterate over each line of the file, then you could do something like this:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  echo "$line"  # $line is a variable that represents the current line in the file
done < "$3"
```

The above example would just echo each line in the file, so you would want to add a counter/logic into the while loop that would allow you to execute whatever you want to do on specific lines and replace the echo statement.

Comment: See [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169765/338177).

Comment: That's a good read, thanks for posting it. I was mostly trying to keep this as simple as possible, but it's probably best to not send people down a bad path if they're just starting out regardless of it being easier. Thanks!

Comment: `sed`, `grep`, `awk` are the usual suspects to process text files :)

Comment: At the least, `while IFS= read -r line; do` so that you don't get word splitting on whitespace, and then double-quote variables when you use them, so `echo "$line"` and `done <"$3"`

Comment: I'll edit the answer to include this.